# How can I enable/disable a jail using fail2ban?

Tags: bash, security, fail2ban, jails

We can add a line like this below a specific jail in the jail.local file, and control the jail:

```
enabled = true/false
```

But I think there should be a command to do this, as we've got bunch of "set" commands here:
https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Commands

But I can't find a related command for doing this. I don't want to do it manually, anybody knows a command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to create a file `/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/service.local` or edit `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```
[service]
enabled = true
```

Don't forget to restart fail2ban:

```
systemctl restart fail2ban.service
```

If you don't want a jail, simply remove this file or configuration lines.

You can check running jails with:

```
fail2ban-client status
```

Comment: 1. instead of a file per jail `jail.d/service.local` one can add all jails to `jail.local`.
2. a restart is not necessary here, a reload would be enough - then it'd start freshly enabled jail(s) only, without to restart another jails.